# Center table, even if it is wider than parent container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a scenario in which the width of the HTML page is limited (with `max-width`) so that the text on the page doesn't become too wide (and hard to read).

I also have some data presented in tables (which are centered), which works fine, as long as the table fit inside the parent container. But sometimes a table becomes wider than the parent element, at which point it stops being centered and instead becomes aligned to the left.

Is there a way to center a table so that it stays centered *even if it overflows its parent?*

Given that my HTML looks like this, what CSS would be required to accomplish this?

```
<div class=content>
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  <table>
      ...
  </table>
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

BTW. It might be obvious, but I'm only talking about horizontal centering here.

Here's a fiddle with my scenario: http://jsfiddle.net/zrajm/tnAS3/

Comment: This is impossible, if an element overflows its container, there's no way it can measure margins on either side.

Comment: You can just use `margin: 0 auto;` on the CSS of `table`.

Comment: `margin: 0 auto;` on the table *only* works if the table fits inside its parent element. It is *not* the way to go here.

Comment: I can center the table as desired *if* the width of the container is fixed. At the moment the container has `max-width: 20em`, so I can perfectly center the table when the container width is 20em, but it becomes slightly off center as the window width is reduced. Interested?

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks Impossible without using Javascript, you mean?

Comment: @thirtydot Sounds interesting, but why the teasing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS `margin: 0 auto;` only works as long as the table fits inside its parent element, if the table grows larger than that it becomes left aligned.

In order to center a table that is wider than its parent one need to set a negative left margin. If one knows the exact dimensions of the table, this can be done directly in CSS (using something like `margin-left: -130px`). If the width of the table can vary, however, the only way to achieve this is to use Javascript to adjust the left margin.

(Below code assumes jQuery, and the HTML structure described in the question.)

```
var contentWidth = $('.content').width();
$('table').each(function (i, table) {
    var tableWidth, margin;
    table = $(table);
    tableWidth = table.width();
    if (tableWidth > contentWidth) {
        margin = (tableWidth - contentWidth) / 2;
        table.css('margin-left', '-' + margin + 'px');
    }
});
```

The above script will look for tables wider than `.content`, and modify only their left margins.

(There is also a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zrajm/tnAS3/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I would try adding `margin: 0 auto;` into the style of a div specifically surrounding the table. This should put it at the center of whatever its parent is.

```
<div class=content>
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  <div style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <table>
      ...
    </table>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: But in this test it fails where the .content is constrained to a width less then the table, http://jsfiddle.net/2vQWX/.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
.calss  
{    
    margin:auto;    
    width:??px ;        
    height:??px ;/*(or auto)*/        
}
```

with this code, any things in your  are center margin.
and when you declare a fixed width for your  the table can't widther than it.
also you can give a width and height for your table.

Answer (score 0):

#### For just this HTML, *no need to change the HTML part*:

```
<div class=content>
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  <table>
      ...
  </table>
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

#### The CSS would be:

```
table {margin: 0 auto;} /* You can set your width */
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/svHvR/1/

Comment: The whole question is about a table that is wider then its parent, not smaller.

Comment: Works, but only if the width of the table is known. But it could be used dynamically with some Javascript to calculate each tables margins depending on actual width.

Comment: @HenrikAmmer, the answer below with two votes will be the right one. :) I guess my answer requires the table's `width` to be known.

Comment: You use a negative `margin` in your fiddle (which is the way to do this) but it's not actually mentioned in your answer above.