# Centering HTML table wider than body

Tags: html, html-table, center

When an HTML table is wider than the page body, it's always left aligned, no matter if you specified a centered alignment. I've a table containing CSS3 gradient buttons, whose size isn't easy to predict (buttons size depends on the font used by the browser). On some browsers this table grows wider than the page body, causing the table to become uncentered related to the page banner.

I've read questions like this: [Center table, even if it is wider than parent container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195418/center-table-even-if-it-is-wider-than-parent-container) stating that the only way of centering tables in this scenario is with Javascript.

But I'd wish to find a solution without javascript. The page design is very simple (just the site logo centered on the header, and an array of big buttons below).

Do you have any suggestion for an easy and elegant solution for this, so that the buttons table is always centered in the page?

Comment: Could you give us an example of your code? You can use http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Some example of what I'm trying to do can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/TuHQb/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/JQ3qb/

I'm not sure but is, this what you want? You can do it with positioning and then play with left percentage to adjust table.

```
#test{
    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 800px;
    position:relative;
    left: -25%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: I cannot use pixel units, because I'm not working with pixels ( buttons on the table cells are CSS3 rendered with fonts and gradients, without using images). I'm actually using these buttons: http://www.red-team-design.com/just-another-awesome-css3-buttons